# Why did Saladin show kindness to Richard I?

Tags: crusades, richard-i, saladin, 12th-century

Why did Saladin, when Richard the Lionhearted was sick with a fever, send him a gift of fruit? Or when Richard's horse was killed in battle, he sent a steed to be led to his camp?

Comment: the recorded reasons (which can be known to historians) might be different from the actual one.

Comment: I second @LouisRhys, I wouldn't consider any of these historical facts - more a legend that might be based on real facts but distorted them very significantly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Saladin was an unusual man who tried to win the "hearts and minds" of people he conquered.

When he reclaimed Jerusalem, he ordered his men NOT to kill and plunder (in contrast even to the crusaders).

When he ruled Cairo, Egypt, he built hospitals and universities for the city, even though he had to take harsh measures against the leaders of his former enemies.

In his dealings with the Crusaders, he allowed them to "save face" by permitting Christian pilgrimages to Jerusalem, even though he controlled the city. In an era when chivalry was just developing in Europe, Saladin won the reputation of being exceptionally "chivalrous." He and Richard I each became the other's "favorite" opponent.

Comment: This is slightly misleading, in that Saladin *did* in fact commit a few minor atrocities (or his armies did at least), although rather less so than most previous Muslim crusaders and many Christian crusaders.

Comment: While Jerusalem was not sacked, all Christian had to be ransomed before being allowed to leave. Sure, the price was really low (10 denari for men, 5 for women and 1 for a child) but still some 15,000 could not afford it and were taken in slavery.  Source: T. F. Madden in Crusades http://www.amazon.co.uk/Crusades-Illustrated-History-Christendom-Pilgrimage/dp/1844830403/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1319534996&sr=1-3

Comment: @Noldorin:"rather less so than most." Many would say, "it's all relative." Especially for the TIMES.

Comment: @Sardathrion: See my note to Noldorin.

Comment: @TomAu: Not a problem at all.  I wanted to add more information as I knew it.  Not meant to offend or claim you did not know yourself.  ^_~

Comment: @Tom Ay: I think you misunderstand my point. His actions generally weren't as atrocious as other contemporary generals.

Comment: @Noldorin: That's the point. He was good on the CURVE.

Comment: @Tom Au: Oh okay, so you're just agreeing me ha. :-P

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this truly did happen, there are a couple of reasons that might explain why. First of all, Saladin was Muslim, and one of the of the main principles of Islam  is that Muslims should help those in need. Secondly, Saladin could use this as an opportunity to send men into Richard's camp and report back on the condition and size of Richard's army, thereby giving Saladin a strategic advantage.

Comment: The second point may very well be true. There is a story/legend that Richard sent an emissary with a gift. Saladin discovered that emissary was actually there to investigate the camp and assess Saladin's strength. Saladin was amused and allowed the emissary full access to his camp.

Comment: And if I remember correctly, it wasn't long after that before they both decided to call a truce. The Crusaders agreed to break off and leave in exchange of Saladin's agreement to allow Christian pilgrimages to return to the Holy Lands under his protection.

Comment: Saying "one of the main principles of Islam is that Muslims should help those in need" is a bit misleading. While this it is perfectly true that this is stated in the Qur'an, as it is stated to Christians in the Bible, it is far from all Christians or Muslims who follow this principle regularly. It would more more accurate to say that Saladin was a man of honour to some degree, and had respect for King Richard's courage and skills. The same was true in reverse.

Comment: +1 definitely for the second point and *not* for the first, as per @Noldorin comment.

Comment: Indeed, Saladin as well as arguably being an honourable general, nonetheless would have used spying tactics as well as anyone!

Comment: You do realize that Muslims are taught to hate Christians and Jews.

Comment: It's not about morality. Saladin has enemies within islam as well as crusader. Those we think are our enemies are not necessarily harmful and those we think are friends are not necessarily useful. Giving a horse is but a trivial cost. It gets Richard out, and it saves tons of lives. Good bargain.

Answer (score 5):

I believe Saladin showed kindness to Richard the Lionheart not because of religion or to spy, though that is a distinct possibility, but because of Saladin's respect towards Richard, even though they were enemies. This respect of an enemy is common throughout history, though not expressed like Saladin with gifts. Julius Caesar had respect for Pompey, Hannibal for Scipio Africanus, Genghis Khan towards Jelaudin, even in world war one there was a deep respect between Australia and the Turkish.

Comment: Do you have any reference or evidence for this respect?