# What gift did Saladin send to Richard when he was ill?

Tags: crusades, richard-i, saladin

What gift did Saladin send to Richard when he was ill?
This is a question I got asked in m H|W and I didn't find it. Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: What is an "m H|W" ?

Comment: There is a question on H:SE that says [it was fruit](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/92/why-did-saladin-show-kindness-to-richard-i?rq=1); google returns a website that says it was ice.  What did your research indicate?

Comment: Fruit and vegetables are the commonly mentioned articles that were gifted. I have heard that Lebanese cucumbers were part of the gift and that some of the seeds of these were brought back to England. All this is anecdotal, though.

Comment: H/W = homework no?

Answer (score 2):

In his book [The Crusades: The War for the Holy Land](https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=1849837708), Thomas Asbridge states that [Angevin envoys requested "fruit and ice"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rK8nA9U0OE4C&dq=%22angevin%20envoys%20requesting%20%22fruit%20and%20ice%22%20for%20their%20king%22&q=%22fruit%20and%20ice%22#v=snippet&q=%22fruit%20and%20ice%22&f=false) from Saladin when Richard I was ill.

Answer (score -4):

Saladin Send the Fruits and Ice to Sir Richard when he was sick. There was a big war going on between Muslims and Christians For the Holy Land of Jerusalem. And Christion Leader Let Muslims took control of Jerusalem because of King Richard who was impressed by Muslims. Sir Richard let Muslim rule Jerusalem.